# Create new row for each column in Excel for MySQL import

Tags: mysql, excel

I got an old database that I need to migrate to my new setup.

The current one holds information about a person, where 5 of the columns is indication on how many children a person got with their age.

Here's my Excel-dump:

```
id  child1  child2  child3  child4  child5
-------------------------------------------
39    30                
41    33      30      21
```

I need to convert this into many rows so that I can import it into my new table (with birthyear = 2014-age).

This is how my relationship table should look like with from the example above:

```
birthyear   person_id
---------------------
1984           39
1981           41
1984           41
1993           41
```

Is it possible to accomplish this in Excel with some formulas?

The database (excel sheet) includes over 40 000 entries, and the majority of these got no child at all (child1-5 NULL).

I'm using Excel for Mac 2011 v14.1.

Comment: You could convert it in excel, but I think it's better to construct a query on old table to return data in new format

Comment: That's a good idea I guess! Problem is I only got the database in Excel. But I guess I could create something temporary to accomplish this. Hoped there was an easier solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I solved my problem in MySQL instead of Excel.

I cleaned up my excel file and created a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `child1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I then imported my data into this table, and solved everything by exporting the result of queries for all 5 columns, like so:

```
SELECT id, (2014-child1) AS birthyear FROM person WHERE child1 IS NOT NULL;
....
SELECT id, (2014-child5) AS birthyear FROM person WHERE child5 IS NOT NULL;
```

Now I got 5 .csv that I can either merge or import one by one.

Comment: Use UNION ALL to combine queries and get 1 result